# Automatic Email from Google Sheets with email from row

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to apply this code to a google sheet which I use to track name change requests.  The customer submits a form and when they don't submit all the required information I select rejected from the dropdown on the spreadsheet. I have the form collect the username when the customer submits the form.  I was wondering if it is possible to modify the code below to grab the email address from the row of the active cell that the status was changed and email the customer to inform them their request is rejected.

```
function sendEmail(email_address, email_subject, email_message) {
  var status = ScriptProperties.getProperty('Order Status') + "";
  var value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("FCNC        Responses").getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  if (value.match("Rejected" ) && status.match("")) { 
    ScriptProperties.setProperty('Order Status', '') 
    MailApp.sendEmail('username@nps.gov', 'Rejected Fleet Card Name Change', '.    Fleer User, Please review the Fleet Card Name Change page for Status Updates.": ');
  }
  else { 
    if (!value.match("Rejected" )) 
      ScriptProperties.setProperty('Order Status', '') 
  }
}
```

Comment: The `auto` tag does not apply here. At least include a tag for the programming language you are using.

Comment: Thanks - I'm new to this, thanks for helping me get my bearings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function with **`dataRange.getValues()`**.

> [**`getValues()`**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
>
> - Returns the rectangular grid of values for this range. Returns a two-dimensional array of values, indexed by row, then by column. The values may be of type **`Number`**, **`Boolean`**, **`Date`**, or **`String`**, depending on the value of the cell. Empty cells will be represented by an empty string in the array. Remember that while a range index starts at **`1, 1`**, the JavaScript array will be indexed from **`[0][0]`**.

Here is a code sample from a related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24786048/5995040):

```
function findCell() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var row = "";
    for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) { 
      if (values[i][j] == "User") {
        row = values[i][j+1];
        Logger.log(row);
        Logger.log(i); // This is your row number
      }
    } 
  } 
}
```

From there you can add the code that will send email if the value of the specific cell is rejected.

Happy coding, hope it helps!